# Selenium: Get code source of innerHTML that doesn't show in 'inspect element'

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

Good day!

I have been looking around the whole internet and I didn't find any problem like mine.

I'm trying to get data using selenium from 'https://mobile.bet9ja.com/mobile' I have navigated to the path I needed step by step, till I got to the page I wanted.

That page loads a picture, then after some time numbers and data that I'm looking for.

My full code is:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import lxml
from selenium import webdriver
import selenium
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains

log_in_url = 'https://mobile.bet9ja.com/mobile/login'
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/macbook/Downloads/chromedriver')
driver.get(log_in_url)
user_name = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input.form-input[type='text']")
password = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input.form-input[type='password']")
log_in_button = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('button')
user_name.clear()
password.clear()
# It needs log in
user_name.send_keys('user_name')
password.send_keys('password')
log_in_button.click()
time.sleep(5)

try:
    # Close a pop up window
    close_pop_up_window = driver.find_element_by_class_name('modal-close')
    close_pop_up_window.click()
except:
    pass

time.sleep(2)
league_button = driver.find_element_by_id('iconslider_1549_league_element')
league_button.click()
time.sleep(6)
premiere_legue = driver.find_element_by_class_name('col-xs-6')
premiere_legue.click()
time.sleep(15)
```

after that I have tried all these codes and they return the same result:

```
html = driver.page_source()
```

and

```
html = driver.execute_script("return document.body.innerHTML")
```

and

```
html = driver.execute_script("return document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML")
```

The result is:

```
<html><head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"><script type="text/javascript" src="https://bam.nr-data.net/1/c95cd51526?a=214311961&amp;v=1167.2a4546b&amp;to=ZlBXZxcAVkEHV0NbDV8aYEEMTlpXEg1dU09cWldaCQQXXglTXlxNWFtRVh1PSFoW&amp;rst=363&amp;ref=https://vsmobile.bet9ja.com/bet9ja-mobile/login/&amp;ap=5&amp;be=322&amp;fe=360&amp;dc=355&amp;perf=%7B%22timing%22:%7B%22of%22:1588686621313,%22n%22:0,%22u%22:310,%22ue%22:310,%22f%22:4,%22dn%22:5,%22dne%22:5,%22c%22:5,%22s%22:95,%22ce%22:187,%22rq%22:187,%22rp%22:301,%22rpe%22:305,%22dl%22:313,%22di%22:355,%22ds%22:355,%22de%22:359,%22dc%22:360,%22l%22:360,%22le%22:361%7D,%22navigation%22:%7B%7D%7D&amp;fp=360&amp;at=ShdUEV8aRU8%3D&amp;jsonp=NREUM.setToken"></script><script src="https://js-agent.newrelic.com/nr-1167.min.js"></script><script type="text/javascript">(window.NREUM||(NREUM={})).loader_config={licenseKey:"c95cd51526",applicationID:"214311961"};window.NREUM||(NREUM={}),__nr_require=function(e,n,t){function r(t){if(!n[t]){var i=n[t]={exports:{}};e[t][0].call(i.exports,function(n){var i=e[t][1][n];return r(i||n)},i,i.exports)}return n[t].exports}if("function"==typeof __nr_require)return __nr_require;for(var i=0;i<t.length;i++)r(t[i]);return r}({1:[function(e,n,t){function r(){}function i(e,n,t){return function(){return o(e,[u.now()].concat(f(arguments)),n?null:this,t),n?void 0:this}}var o=e("handle"),a=e(4),f=e(5),c=e("ee").get("tracer"),u=e("loader"),s=NREUM;"undefined"==typeof window.newrelic&&(newrelic=s);var p=["setPageViewName","setCustomAttribute","setErrorHandler","finished","addToTrace","inlineHit","addRelease"],l="api-",d=l+"ixn-";a(p,function(e,n){s[n]=i(l+n,!0,"api")}),s.addPageAction=i(l+"addPageAction",!0),s.setCurrentRouteName=i(l+"routeName",!0),n.exports=newrelic,s.interaction=function(){return(new r).get()};var m=r.prototype={createTracer:function(e,n){var t={},r=this,i="function"==typeof n;return o(d+"tracer",[u.now(),e,t],r),function(){if(c.emit((i?"":"no-")+"fn-start",[u.now(),r,i],t),i)try{return n.apply(this,arguments)}catch(e){throw c.emit("fn-err",[arguments,this,e],t),e}finally{c.emit("fn-end",[u.now()],t)}}}};a("actionText,setName,setAttribute,save,ignore,onEnd,getContext,end,get".split(","),function(e,n){m[n]=i(d+n)}),newrelic.noticeError=function(e,n){"string"==typeof e&&(e=new Error(e)),o("err",[e,u.now(),!1,n])}},{}],2:[function(e,n,t){function r(e,n){var t=e.getEntries();t.forEach(function(e){"first-paint"===e.name?c("timing",["fp",Math.floor(e.startTime)]):"first-contentful-paint"===e.name&&c("timing",["fcp",Math.floor(e.startTime)])})}function i(e,n){var t=e.getEntries();t.length>0&&c("lcp",[t[t.length-1]])}function o(e){if(e instanceof s&&!l){var n,t=Math.round(e.timeStamp);n=t>1e12?Date.now()-t:u.now()-t,l=!0,c("timing",["fi",t,{type:e.type,fid:n}])}}if(!("init"in NREUM&&"page_view_timing"in NREUM.init&&"enabled"in NREUM.init.page_view_timing&&NREUM.init.page_view_timing.enabled===!1)){var a,f,c=e("handle"),u=e("loader"),s=NREUM.o.EV;if("PerformanceObserver"in window&&"function"==typeof window.PerformanceObserver){a=new PerformanceObserver(r),f=new PerformanceObserver(i);try{a.observe({entryTypes:["paint"]}),f.observe({entryTypes:["largest-contentful-paint"]})}catch(p){}}if("addEventListener"in document){var l=!1,d=["click","keydown","mousedown","pointerdown","touchstart"];d.forEach(function(e){document.addEventListener(e,o,!1)})}}},{}],3:[function(e,n,t){function r(e,n){if(!i)return!1;if(e!==i)return!1;if(!n)return!0;if(!o)return!1;for(var t=o.split("."),r=n.split("."),a=0;a<r.length;a++)if(r[a]!==t[a])return!1;return!0}var i=null,o=null,a=/Version\/(\S+)\s+Safari/;if(navigator.userAgent){var f=navigator.userAgent,c=f.match(a);c&&f.indexOf("Chrome")===-1&&f.indexOf("Chromium")===-1&&(i="Safari",o=c[1])}n.exports={agent:i,version:o,match:r}},{}],4:[function(e,n,t){function r(e,n){var t=[],r="",o=0;for(r in e)i.call(e,r)&&(t[o]=n(r,e[r]),o+=1);return t}var i=Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty;n.exports=r},{}],5:[function(e,n,t){function r(e,n,t){n||(n=0),"undefined"==typeof t&&(t=e?e.length:0);for(var r=-1,i=t-n||0,o=Array(i<0?0:i);++r<i;)o[r]=e[n+r];return o}n.exports=r},{}],6:[function(e,n,t){n.exports={exists:"undefined"!=typeof window.performance&&window.performance.timing&&"undefined"!=typeof window.performance.timing.navigationStart}},{}],ee:[function(e,n,t){function r(){}function i(e){function n(e){return e&&e instanceof r?e:e?c(e,f,o):o()}function t(t,r,i,o){if(!l.aborted||o){e&&e(t,r,i);for(var a=n(i),f=v(t),c=f.length,u=0;u<c;u++)f[u].apply(a,r);var p=s[y[t]];return p&&p.push([b,t,r,a]),a}}function d(e,n){h[e]=v(e).concat(n)}function m(e,n){var t=h[e];if(t)for(var r=0;r<t.length;r++)t[r]===n&&t.splice(r,1)}function v(e){return h[e]||[]}function g(e){return p[e]=p[e]||i(t)}function w(e,n){u(e,function(e,t){n=n||"feature",y[t]=n,n in s||(s[n]=[])})}var h={},y={},b={on:d,addEventListener:d,removeEventListener:m,emit:t,get:g,listeners:v,context:n,buffer:w,abort:a,aborted:!1};return b}function o(){return new r}function a(){(s.api||s.feature)&&(l.aborted=!0,s=l.backlog={})}var f="nr@context",c=e("gos"),u=e(4),s={},p={},l=n.exports=i();l.backlog=s},{}],gos:[function(e,n,t){function r(e,n,t){if(i.call(e,n))return e[n];var r=t();if(Object.defineProperty&&Object.keys)try{return Object.defineProperty(e,n,{value:r,writable:!0,enumerable:!1}),r}catch(o){}return e[n]=r,r}var i=Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty;n.exports=r},{}],handle:[function(e,n,t){function r(e,n,t,r){i.buffer([e],r),i.emit(e,n,t)}var i=e("ee").get("handle");n.exports=r,r.ee=i},{}],id:[function(e,n,t){function r(e){var n=typeof e;return!e||"object"!==n&&"function"!==n?-1:e===window?0:a(e,o,function(){return i++})}var i=1,o="nr@id",a=e("gos");n.exports=r},{}],loader:[function(e,n,t){function r(){if(!x++){var e=E.info=NREUM.info,n=d.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];if(setTimeout(s.abort,3e4),!(e&&e.licenseKey&&e.applicationID&&n))return s.abort();u(y,function(n,t){e[n]||(e[n]=t)}),c("mark",["onload",a()+E.offset],null,"api");var t=d.createElement("script");t.src="https://"+e.agent,n.parentNode.insertBefore(t,n)}}function i(){"complete"===d.readyState&&o()}function o(){c("mark",["domContent",a()+E.offset],null,"api")}function a(){return O.exists&&performance.now?Math.round(performance.now()):(f=Math.max((new Date).getTime(),f))-E.offset}var f=(new Date).getTime(),c=e("handle"),u=e(4),s=e("ee"),p=e(3),l=window,d=l.document,m="addEventListener",v="attachEvent",g=l.XMLHttpRequest,w=g&&g.prototype;NREUM.o={ST:setTimeout,SI:l.setImmediate,CT:clearTimeout,XHR:g,REQ:l.Request,EV:l.Event,PR:l.Promise,MO:l.MutationObserver};var h=""+location,y={beacon:"bam.nr-data.net",errorBeacon:"bam.nr-data.net",agent:"js-agent.newrelic.com/nr-1167.min.js"},b=g&&w&&w[m]&&!/CriOS/.test(navigator.userAgent),E=n.exports={offset:f,now:a,origin:h,features:{},xhrWrappable:b,userAgent:p};e(1),e(2),d[m]?(d[m]("DOMContentLoaded",o,!1),l[m]("load",r,!1)):(d[v]("onreadystatechange",i),l[v]("onload",r)),c("mark",["firstbyte",f],null,"api");var x=0,O=e(6)},{}],"wrap-function":[function(e,n,t){function r(e){return!(e&&e instanceof Function&&e.apply&&!e[a])}var i=e("ee"),o=e(5),a="nr@original",f=Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty,c=!1;n.exports=function(e,n){function t(e,n,t,i){function nrWrapper(){var r,a,f,c;try{a=this,r=o(arguments),f="function"==typeof t?t(r,a):t||{}}catch(u){l([u,"",[r,a,i],f])}s(n+"start",[r,a,i],f);try{return c=e.apply(a,r)}catch(p){throw s(n+"err",[r,a,p],f),p}finally{s(n+"end",[r,a,c],f)}}return r(e)?e:(n||(n=""),nrWrapper[a]=e,p(e,nrWrapper),nrWrapper)}function u(e,n,i,o){i||(i="");var a,f,c,u="-"===i.charAt(0);for(c=0;c<n.length;c++)f=n[c],a=e[f],r(a)||(e[f]=t(a,u?f+i:i,o,f))}function s(t,r,i){if(!c||n){var o=c;c=!0;try{e.emit(t,r,i,n)}catch(a){l([a,t,r,i])}c=o}}function p(e,n){if(Object.defineProperty&&Object.keys)try{var t=Object.keys(e);return t.forEach(function(t){Object.defineProperty(n,t,{get:function(){return e[t]},set:function(n){return e[t]=n,n}})}),n}catch(r){l([r])}for(var i in e)f.call(e,i)&&(n[i]=e[i]);return n}function l(n){try{e.emit("internal-error",n)}catch(t){}}return e||(e=i),t.inPlace=u,t.flag=a,t}},{}]},{},["loader"]);</script>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Adapter</title>
    <!-- DEPENDENCIES -->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/login_favicon.ico">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu:400,700,400italic" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="css/sportsbook.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,500,700">
    <link href="css/demo.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/loginBetin.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/login.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="plugins/bootstrap-3.3.7-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="plugins/jquery-1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="plugins/bootstrap-3.3.7-dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Javascript client-side code -->

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var lang = "";
        function openSelection(mode, uri){
            var url  = "https://vsmobile.bet9ja.com" + uri + (uri.indexOf('?') ? "&mode=" : "?mode=") + mode + "&lang=" + lang;
            window.location.replace(url);
        }

        function backToMain(){
            var url = "https://mobile.bet9ja.com/Mobile";
            window.location.replace(url);
        }
    </script>


    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/grapi.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<div class="container" id="product" style="display: none">
</div>

<div class="container" id="playarea" style="">
    <script>
        var isLoaded = false;

        function onLoadIframe(iframe) {
            if (!isLoaded) {
        //      iframe.src = '?game=league&OTP=98405c34-4f92-4db7-b993-7562953d2604&mode=premier&lang='; // './index-iframe-content.html' + window.location.search;
                if( iframe.src != "" )
                {
                    isLoaded = true;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                goBackUrl();
            }
        }

        eventMethod = window.addEventListener ? "addEventListener" : "attachEvent";
        eventer = window[eventMethod];
        messageEvent = eventMethod == "attachEvent" ? "onmessage" : "message";
        eventer(messageEvent, function (e) {
            let data = e.data.split('$');
            let command = data[0];
            if (command == "goHome") {
                backToMain();
            }
        }, false);
    </script>

    <div style="${bet9ja.iframe.style}">
        <iframe id="playAreaFrame" onload="onLoadIframe(this)" style="
                    position:absolute;top:0;left:0;right:0;bottom:0;width:100%;height:100%;border:0;
                " src="https://vsmobile.bet9ja.com/mobile-1.94.35/themes/?sk=bet9ja&amp;t=644ee448-8fb1-426c-9922-31688a0a85f6&amp;pinHash=53a0d64f55b5986a27e81982ccd000de&amp;pid=14001&amp;v=0&amp;text=Premier&amp;homeUrl=https://mobile.bet9ja.com/Mobile&amp;otp=98405c34-4f92-4db7-b993-7562953d2604&amp;ss=&amp;bl=&amp;vu=0">
        </iframe>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(function() {
        var input       = {"game":"league","OTP":"98405c34-4f92-4db7-b993-7562953d2604","mode":"premier","lang":""};
        var u           = "98405c34-4f92-4db7-b993-7562953d2604";
        var home        = ""; //"https://vsmobile.bet9ja.com/bet9ja-mobile/login/";
        var params      = "&pid=14001&v=0&text=Premier";
        var game        = "league_premier";
        grapi.loggedUser(u,input,home,params,game,true );
    });
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">window.NREUM||(NREUM={});NREUM.info={"beacon":"bam.nr-data.net","licenseKey":"c95cd51526","applicationID":"214311961","transactionName":"ZlBXZxcAVkEHV0NbDV8aYEEMTlpXEg1dU09cWldaCQQXXglTXlxNWFtRVh1PSFoW","queueTime":0,"applicationTime":5,"atts":"ShdUEV8aRU8=","errorBeacon":"bam.nr-data.net","agent":""}</script>
</body></html>
```

I have tried to inspect the webpage using google chrome, and I have noticed that when I inspect the page the first time it shows (Please check the link for a screenshot):

[Screenshot of the code. The arrow points to the place where the code I need will be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VjVH7.png)

and when I inspect it for the second time I get the code I need.

I have really invested a lot of time searching for any solutions, but I got nothing.
I will be so happy to find a solution here.

Thanks a lot

Comment: the page have an iframe so my suggestion is you should directly go for that iframe url instead of the parent page and get the code from that original page.

Comment: you can solve this by adding some explicit wait and scrape the data you need. It does have an iframe and make sure to switch to it before scraping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks a lot @Sureshmani and @Anees Ijaz for your comments.

So after you suggestions, the solution waas to switch to the iframe, so that's what solved my problem:

```
iframe = driver.find_element_by_id('playAreaFrame')
driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)
print(driver.page_source)
driver.switch_to.default_content() #To switch back to the original content
```

Thanks a lot guys